# ES6 default value - help understand the concept

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to develop my JS skills and start to exploit ES6.

I understand that you can assign defaults and I'm trying this in a module:

```
export var updateWidget = function (type = 'image', {
    previewId = '.image-preview',
    filepath = 'content/articles',
    baseUrl = 'http://dummy.com',
    thumbSize = '400x400'
}) {


    var options = {
            previewId: previewId,
            type: type
        },
        fileElements = {
            filepath: filepath,
            thumbPath: null,
            baseUrl: baseUrl,
            thumbSize: thumbSize

        },
}
```

If I then initiate the object like this:

```
new updateWidget('image'
            ).update('5059-081.png');
```

I get a `cannot read property undefined` relating to the default object. If I do this:

```
new updateWidget('image', {}
            ).update('5059-081.png');
```

It works.

It seems strange that I need to pass a blank object to the module to get this to work, I would have expected to leave it out altogether the defaults would have still worked.

I'm looking to update the current module pattern I use to fully exploit ES6 but one step at a time.

So, how can I set defaults and only optionally need to send an object? What's the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument expects an object which will be destructured.

When it is destructured, each of the variables produced is given a default value, in case the object doesn't have a matching property.

There is no default value given for what should be destructured if there is no argument passed.

You could set an empty object as the default value.

```
export var updateWidget = function (type = 'image', {
    previewId = '.image-preview',
    filepath = 'content/articles',
    baseUrl = 'http://dummy.com',
    thumbSize = '400x400'
} = {})
```

(Note the change on the last line)

Comment: Thank you - I misunderstood, I thought simply setting the default object with the defaults within it was enough - totally makes sense now - pass a default blank object. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the second argument optional, you need to provide a default value for it. You've provided defaults for the destructuring you're doing of it, but not the actual parameter itself. As a result, you're trying to destructure the value `undefined`, which is why you get the error.

Provide a default for the parameter you're destructuring, like this:

```
    export var updateWidget = function (type = 'image', {
        previewId = '.image-preview',
        filepath = 'content/articles',
        baseUrl = 'http://dummy.com',
        thumbSize = '400x400'
    } = {}) {
// −−^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
const updateWidget = function (type = 'image', {
    previewId = '.image-preview',
    filepath = 'content/articles',
    baseUrl = 'http://dummy.com',
    thumbSize = '400x400'
} = {}) {
    console.log(`type = ${type}`);
    console.log(`previewId = ${previewId}`);
    console.log(`filepath = ${filepath}`);
    console.log(`baseUrl = ${baseUrl}`);
    console.log(`thumbSize = ${thumbSize}`);
}
console.log("Call 1:");
updateWidget();
console.log("Call 2:");
updateWidget(undefined, {filepath: "/different/path"});
console.log("Call 3:");
updateWidget("mytype", {filepath: "/different/path"});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - makes sense now, destructuring is a new concept - more research and thanks for the resolution and snippet

Comment: @Ray - No worries! FWIW, I go into destructuring and parameter defaults in a fair bit of detail in my new book out in a couple of months. If you're interested, see my profile for details. ;-)

Comment: crowder - thank you - I'll keep an eye out for it - :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have set the default properties of the second argument, but you have yet to make it optional.

Simply set its default value to an empty object, like so :

```
export var updateWidget = function (type = 'image', {
    previewId = '.image-preview',
    filepath = 'content/articles',
    baseUrl = 'http://dummy.com',
    thumbSize = '400x400'
} = {}) { // <= Setting the default value as empty object


    var options = {
            previewId: previewId,
            type: type
        },
        fileElements = {
            filepath: filepath,
            thumbPath: null,
            baseUrl: baseUrl,
            thumbSize: thumbSize

        },
}
```

Comment: That's great - thank you. really appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Since the second argument is `undefined`, Destructuring does not work on undefined values.

You can do something like this `const getItem = (type = "image", { previewId. ="abc" } = {}) => {}`

Comment: Thank you - I now understand the default blank object - can you explain the use of the arrow? I've read a bit on those but that hasn't sunk in

Comment: well an arrow function don't have their own bindings, means that if you use `this` inside them then `this` would represent its parent binding

Comment: Thanks again - i've read up on this now and what you say makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The following is valid, but when supplied with `undefined` it will throw a `TypeError` because `undefined` is not a type suitable for destructuring.

```js
function foo({ a = 'a' }) {
  console.log(a)
}

foo() // TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
```

In order to have your code fail gracefully, you can supply an empty object as a default argument. **The reason it works like this is that silently "saving" the programmer from this error would reduce the expressiveness of the language by making it impossible to discriminate (in this scenario) between passing `undefined` or `null` to such a function and passing an empty object.**

```js
function foo({ a = 'a' } = {}) {
  console.log(a)
}

foo() // 'a'
```

If you are not using destructuring, then default arguments will take effect in the normal way:

```js
function foo(a = 'a') {
  console.log(a)
}

foo() // 'a'
```